# why is that when hovering over my horizontal menus the submenus disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a horizontal style menu when hovering over it, and trying to hover over its list items and submenus, the menu disappears.

```css
#main_nav:before,
#main_nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#main_nav {
  zoom: 1;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 350px;
}
#main_nav li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#main_nav li a {
  text-align: center;
}
#main_nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 110px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: solid;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#main_nav li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: -3px;
}
#main_nav > li:hover {
  border-bottom: solid red;
}
#main_nav >li:hover > ul {
  top: 30px;
}
#main_nav ul ul {
  left: 110px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="main_nav">
  <li>TITLE 1
    <ul>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>TITLE 2
    <ul>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>TITLE 3
    <ul>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>TITLE 4
    <ul>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>TITLE 5
    <ul>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>TITLE 6
    <ul>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>TITLE 7
    <ul>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>SUBMENU 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So when hovering over the menus, and then the submenus pop up and when i try to hover over the submenu, they disappear, why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the ul is too far from the li, so when you try to reach the  the hover state is disabled.

Try the following CSS:

```
#main_nav:before,
#main_nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#main_nav {
  zoom: 1;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 350px;
}
#main_nav li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#main_nav li a {
  text-align: center;
}
#main_nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 110px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: solid;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#main_nav li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: -3px;
}
#main_nav > li:hover {
  border-bottom: solid red;
}
#main_nav >li:hover > ul {
  top: 30px;
}
#main_nav ul ul {
  left: 110px;
}

/* To make the first li higher */
#main_nav > li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
/* To make the li's inside ul wider */
#main_nav ul > li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: can you comment or highlight the code changes in yoru css?

Comment: oh i c, you reduced the top position in #main_nav ul...see thats the problem i need it to be further down, literally at 50px..

Comment: actually can you xplain to me the logic here?

Comment: I just "extended" the li's with the pseudo class :after. Try to add background colors to the selectors I added to understand how it works. This is a dirty fix, but it's a solution.

Comment: ok got it...but before i didn't have to worry about "connecting" the li's of the submenu(ie when you make an dummy li inside the submenus).  I didn't need to do this before, y now?

Comment: actually nvm ur right, i did need those i just didn't realize till now.  Again thanks!